# Software Updater missing from System Tools

Tags: lubuntu

Just installed my first Ubuntu system. It's Lubuntu build 18.10
I read an article that indicated the first thing to do was check for updates by clicking on System Tools / Software Updater.  However, Software Updater is not listed. 
How do I install that (noob here).
Steve

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93152/discussion-on-question-by-spike-software-updater-missing-from-system-tools).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue after a fresh install of LUbuntu 18.10. In a terminal I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

Software Updater and Software & Updates shows under preferences.

Comment: Thank you, but that did not help. The Discover window comes up blank.  When I run "sudo plasma-discover" from the terminal, I get error messages that a file "GlobalDrawer.qml" Type Error cannot read property "length" of undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I got the software updater back by installing the package `update-manager`. It was removed after installing Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade, in addition to other problems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149788/failed-to-start-mysql-community-server-in-19-04

Comment: 2023, this worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04. Somehow _just_ "Software Updater" went missing from my Applications when updating to 22.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to check the package on Muon Package Manager under systems tools. On the search bar type, plasma discover and the following should come up from the search:

plasma-discover-common, plasma-discover-snap-backend, plasma-discover-flatbackend, and plasma-discover

Install what you need and give it a try. In my system the only package not installed is the flatbackend.