# Failed to start MYSQL community server in 19.04

Tags: apache2, mysql, 19.04, phpmyadmin

I use Linux Ubuntu-19.O4. I was just working on a project where I have to prompt the user to input details using  and that information to be stored in a database for which I used "PHPMYADMIN". All things were going smoothly until I was using Ubuntu 18.10, and when I upgraded my system to 19.04 the things went critical as Apache2 server was active but `sudo systemctl status mysql.service` gives me the following output :

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysql.service
[sudo] password for parth: 
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-06-09 16:23:16 IST; 29min a
  Process: 1167 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit
  Process: 1176 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/my

Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'ex
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Serve
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job,
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'ex
Jun 09 16:23:16 parth-p-pandya systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Serve
```

And also when I try to enter password for phpmyadmin I get the following thing : [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVT3q.jpg)

I'll be pleased if I get any fruitful solution to this error.

Comment: Same problem after Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade, almost every Ubuntu upgrade breaks something, even with LTS. Did you find a solution? I even received a bonus with a kernel panic offered by the Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade! If it continues, I will have to switch to a more serious Linux distribution like Debian...

Comment: Nope yaar! I got nothing solved due to which I dropped my ongoing project!

Comment: When reinstalling MySQL, I noticed the message `MySQL has been frozen to prevent damage to your system. Please see /etc/mysql/FROZEN for help.`. It looks like MySQL binary data of the previous version is not compatible with the new version 5.7. I had to remove the folder `/var/lib/mysql` (keep a backup if you need to export data with a compatible MySQL version) and remove the symlink FROZEN + reinstall mysql-server to make it start.
It sucks that we cannot reuse previous databases. I took this opportunity to switch to MariaDB instead of MySQL, which is the recommended replacement for MySQL.

Comment: I tried to use the backup data with an Ubuntu 18.10 image on VirtualBox but it did not work. I can see this error message in /var/log/mysql/error.log: `[ERROR] InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.3.17. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-downgrading.html`.