# Ubuntu 19.04 failed to boot: Failed to start MySQL Community Server

Tags: boot, server, mysql, recovery-mode

I have a problem with my `Ubuntu 19.04`. As soon as I tried to boot the system it stops and the message I am getting is the following:

`Failed to start MySQL Community Server`

Attached is also a photo I took with my phone of the error isf that can be useful:

[image: my-sql]

What I tried to solve the problem was enetring in recovery mode as is possible to see here:

[image: rec-mode]

I chose the `Clean` option as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098366/ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-boot-faile-to-start-mysql-community-server) had my same problem. 
Unfortunately that didn't solve my problem and I am still stuck at the boot.
I have found [this post too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149788/failed-to-start-mysql-community-server-in-19-04) which is sort of related (I don't have Apache) but in order to go ahead I would already have done the booting and accessing the terminal.

What can I do? 
Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction to solve this problem

Comment: Just not being able to start a database server does not stop Ubuntu from booting. The MySQL error that you see is not the cause of the problems (although it may be caused by them). Choose "Drop to a root shell prompt" and search `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` for other indications of where things go wrong.

Comment: I tried to also `dpkg` and it said that there is no free space. I don't understand because I freed up space last week. I erased 30 GB of files. I did follow your advice and I arrived [here](https://i.imgur.com/5lE9Fg6.jpg)

Comment: `dmesg` is a command, but `/var/log/syslog` is a file. You can navigate through this file using `less /var/log/syslog`. You can navigate through the output of `dmesg` by *piping* it to `less` using `dmesg | less`.

Comment: Thanks, I took some shots of the [less dmseg](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8rwy3l04uigbk9q/AADGJnnW4dy-iZK9jgzXZF8Pa?dl=0) and other for [/var/log/syslog](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6og133x3gge09ei/AAAPyayHTdjNDNa4wSMPviL_a?dl=0). I don't have a lot of experience in navigating through these types of files, so I hope it can be helpful to help understand what is happening. Thank you so far for your help.

Comment: On the first screen it can be seen that your system is (very carefully) booting into recovery mode, with no graphics drivers and with a read-only filesystem. This should allow you to find the cause of the problems, then remount the filesystem as read-write, make some changes, and reboot normally. Now we don't know yet *why* the filesystem is `ro`. It may be mentioned in the `dmesg` log before this point. Please review the `dmesg` output and look for error messages that include "mounting in read-only mode".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after trying to package an app from my laptop to my android phone; I had to run dpkg option from the recovery menu, and it prompted me to make some space, so I deleted the unnecessary files after setting the root partition to write:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

And it worked after rebooting!